# After update to 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu doesn't detect projector anymore

Tags: projector

After I updated from 14 to 16.04, Ubuntu (on my lenovo T530) does not detect projectors anymore. I tried a second screen, that works fine. I connect via VGA to the projector.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

RP

Comment: Same issue here. Can anyone help? Using Ubuntu 16.04 ( lenovo T420 ) and the projector is NEC.